# Is it possible to refactor nested if statements with not much logic inside?

Tags: c#

Is it possible to refactor below code? Because there isn't much logic but many `if` statements. Or there is nothing what I can do because most code contains `if` / `else` statements?

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string returnUrl) 
{
    if (User?.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true)
    {
        if (await _urlService.AccessCodeInUrlExistsAsync(returnUrl))
        {
            string accessCode = await _urlService.GetAccessCodeFromUrlAsync(returnUrl);

            if (await _authService.AccessCodeBelongsToAuthenticatedUserAsync(accessCode))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                await _authService.LogoutAsync(accessCode);
                return RedirectToAction("GetAccessCode");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }                
    }
    else
    {
        if (await _urlService.AccessCodeInUrlExistsAsync(returnUrl))
        {
            string accessCode = await _urlService.GetAccessCodeFromUrlAsync(returnUrl);

            await _authService.LoginAsync(accessCode);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("GetAccessCode");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Each lowest-level if/else branch is doing something different, and I see no way to do a refactor to simplify things.  By the way, given that your code be already working, and you just want some suggestions on how to improve it, your question really belongs on our sister site, [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Up to three `await`s in a single function smells fishy to me, and I agree with reposting to [codereview.se].

Comment: Duplicate lines `_urlService.AccessCodeInUrlExistsAsync` and `_urlService.GetAccessCodeFromUrlAsync` used in both `if` and `else` part. You can call those first to avoid duplicate code. I too agree your code belongs to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Ok, I understand, next time I will publish it on stack exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to observe similair actions, that you can take out of `if` blocks. Here:

```
if (await _urlService.AccessCodeInUrlExistsAsync(returnUrl))
{
    string accessCode = await _urlService.GetAccessCodeFromUrlAsync(returnUrl);
```

could be taken out.

Also , `User?.Identity.IsAuthenticated` could be stored in variable and it would reduce one `if` hopefully:

```
var userAuthenticated = User?.Identity.IsAuthenticated ?? false;
// This call exists in both branches of if, thus we could take it out.
var accessCodeInUrExists = await _urlService.AccessCodeInUrlExistsAsync(returnUrl);

string accessCode = accessCodeInUrExists ? await _urlService.GetAccessCodeFromUrlAsync(returnUrl) : null;

if ( userAuthenticated && accessCode != null)
{
    var accessCodeVerification = await _authService.AccessCodeBelongsToAuthenticatedUserAsync(accessCode);

    if(accessCodeVerification)
        return RedirectToAction("Index");

    await _authService.LogoutAsync(accessCode);
    return RedirectToAction("GetAccessCode");
}
else if( accessCode != null)
{
    await _authService.LoginAsync(accessCode);
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
else
{
    return RedirectToAction("GetAccessCode");
}
```

Please, bear in mind, that I just did that for presentation purporse and you need to carefully test, if this works as desired.

I managed to reduce number of conditional instructions and hopefully made the code more readable with simple if statements.

Answer (score -1):

Can you Try like this:
    NOTE: It's just a Pseudo code to have an idea:

```
if (User?.Identity.IsAuthenticated 
        && await _urlService.AccessCodeInUrlExistsAsync(returnUrl) 
        && await _authService.AccessCodeBelongsToAuthenticatedUserAsync(accessCode)) 
      {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else{
            return RedirectToAction("GetAccessCode");
            }
```

Mark it Answer if it helps

Comment: This answer isn't going to be looked at favourably.

Comment: Please revisit your answer. It doesn't to same business logic. Even your `if` condition block got duplicate calls to same function.

Comment: @MKR Please read my note, it's pseudo code / an idea; not a fully working code. It shouldn't be downvote

Comment: @shyamsundarsinghtomar Though I have not down voted (normally I don't). My feedback was about duplicate lines in your pseudo code itself. Thanks you have corrected. Still I feel your answer has not addressed the problem.